# How to return a json object from html template back to views.py in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, request

In Django, how do I return a json object from html template back to views.py. The JSON object is an array of multiple JSON objects. I would like to return it back to the views.py file so that external get requests to this html webpage can be made to retrieve that JSON object.

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
      // Array to store JSON objects
      var jsonObject = {
        "data": [
        {% for person in persons %}
        {
            "name": "{{ person.name }}",
            "weight": {{ person.weight }},
            "height": {{ person.height }},
            "date of birth": "{{ person.dob }}",
          },
          {% endfor %}
        ]
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>JSON Objects:</h1>
    <pre id="personsDisplay"></pre>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("personsDisplay").textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def test(request):
     n = 10  # Replace with your desired value of N
     youngest_people = Persons.objects.filter(
         country=OuterRef('country')
     ).order_by('age')[:n]
     queryset = Persons.objects.filter(
         id__in=Subquery(youngest_peoples.values('birth'))
     ).order_by('country', '-age')


     context = {
         'persons': queryset
     }

     return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

The views.py is getting the top 10 oldest people from every country, passing that to the test.html to create the custom json object which is an array of the top 10 oldest people from every country json objects which shows their name, weight, height and date of birth. I then return that jsonObject back to views.py. I believe the error might be something to do with return in views.py file but not sure.

Comment: The context contains an item named `person`, but the javascript is looking for something named `persons`.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I've fixed it, but either way, still unable to get the json object to be returned to views.py